# Random slowdowns at random intervals of gameplay. How do I stop these?

Tags: technical-issues, alien-isolation

I've been playing Alien: Isolation for about 10 hours, and loving it, but twice now the game randomly slows down to unplayable frame rates. Lags opening menus whether it be the map, pause menu, or even the movement detector. If I try to alt-tab out to kill the game in Task Manager the game won't even let me do that. The screen will go black, and I will get a frozen blue *busy* icon. The only way to get out of the game is to hard reset my computer which is a pain the butt, and probably not very good for it.

I can't think of what is causing it, because I get solid FPS for hours straight in the game, and then it just randomly starts to lag, and freeze. I'm almost positive nothing is overheating either.

How do I stop the random slowdowns, and freezing at random intervals? Thanks.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/Gr7NaYA9) are my specifications.

Comment: are your drivers up to date, specifically sound card and video card?

Comment: @Ender Yep. They're up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, having read a lot of people speculating that this could be a memory problem and having very similar specs, I disabled my pagefile and used a spare 15gb pen-drive formatted to exFAT and used it as dedicated ReadyBoost. I already had 8GB DDR3-1333 SDRAM, so I wasn't short but I think it may be a bug with the game because other sites say geforce/intel systems doing the same!
So far my 'cure' seems to be working but it's a bit early to tell.